# C# invalid token 'int' in class

Tags: c#, .net

Learning C# from a book and just crashed into this problem: invalid token 'int'in class, struct, or interface member declaration. Im trying to return an array from a method.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace AdvanceMethodConcepts

{
    class Program
    {
        public static void firstElementPrint(int[] a)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The first element is {0}. \n", a[0]);
        }

        public static void printFirstListElement (List<int> a)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The first list element is {0}\n", a[0]);
        }
//this next line has the problem
        public static void int[] ReturnUserInput() 
        {
            int[] a = new int[3];
            for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter an integer ");
                a[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Integer added to array.\n");
                return a;
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] myArray = { 11, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
            firstElementPrint(myArray);

            List<int> myList = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
            printFirstListElement(myList);

            int[] myArray2 = ReturnUserInput();

        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `void` and `int[]` return types are mutually exclusive

Comment: your ReturnUserInput declaration should look like `public static int[] ReturnUserInput()`; Also you return `a` in a very first iteration of your loop. It might not happen at all - and the compiler will complain about it; and most likely you want to return it after the for loop is completed

Comment: And one more thing - while you are writing console applications it will be much easier for you to see the outputs if you add `Console.ReadLine();` at the very end of your Main

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take this:

```
public static void int[] ReturnUserInput()
```

and change it to this:

```
public static int[] ReturnUserInput()
```

`void` is a return type. It means "this function doesn't return anything". When you add `int[]`, you're saying "this function doesn't return anything" and also saying "this function returns an integer array." Those two things contradict each other, and you can only use one return type anyway.

---

While I'm here,  you need to move the `return` statement in the `ReturnUserInput()` function to come *after* the loop. You can also reduce this:

```
public static void firstElementPrint(int[] a)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The first element is {0}. \n", a[0]);
}

public static void printFirstListElement (List<int> a)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The first list element is {0}\n", a[0]);
}
```

Down to just this that you can call with both an `List<int>` *and* an `int[]`:

```
public static void printFirstElement (IList<int> a)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The first list element is {0}\n", a[0]);
}
```

or this, that you can call with any kind of List or array:

```
public static void printFirstElement<T>(IList<T> a)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The first list element is {0}\n", a[0]);
}
```

It works by implicitly calling `ToString()` on whatever item you happen to have.

Answer (score -1):

What I observed is this statement

```
public static void int[] ReturnUserInput()
```

Void states doesn't return anything and you've kept an integer array that you need to be returned. Change it to:

```
public static int[] ReturnUserInput()
```

And remove the return statement from the for loop and put it outside the for loop